# How To Set Require All Properties in Ajv/Fastify?

Tags: fastify, ajv

I Have A Schema Where All Properties Should Be Present, Due To Large Number Of Properties Its Not Good Way To Add Them Manually In *Required Array* , Is There Any Way To Do It ?

**Schema Code**

```
const schema = {
     type: "object",
     properties: {
         foo,
         bar
     },
    required : ['stockid', 'quantity'],
    additionalProperties: false,
}
```

I want all properties required, But I don't wana add each properties manually in required array.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such feature by default.
You need to write a utility function to do it.

```
const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    foo: {},
    bar: {}
  },
  additionalProperties: false
}

const fastifyRouteConfig = {
  schema: {
    body: requireAll(schema)
  }
}

function requireAll (schema) {
  return {
    ...schema,
    required: Object.keys(schema.properties)
  }
}
```

Note that combining it within `onRoute` hook can automate this process because you can manipulate the `schema` object there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (although, not Fastify related) requirement, I ended up just using a getter for this to avoid manually specifying the string array.

```js
const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  get required() {
    return Object.keys(this.properties)
  },
  additionalProperties: false,
  properties: {
    foo: {},
    bar: {}
  }
}
```